# SQL case statement - Select values from third based on 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have 2 databases `db1` and `db2` -

There are 2 tables in `db1` - `movies` & `tickets`.
There is 1 table in `db2` - `boxoffice`.

I want to apply the following logic while fetching results-

```
if boxoffice.movie_id == movie.id
  tickets.movie_id = boxoffice.movie_id
else
  tickets.movie_id = movie.id
end
```

[image: The tables are shown in the image] 
Consider the tickets table to be similar to these

I wrote something like this but it is incomplete -

`select mvoie_id from tickets-- query that i was using...some syntax might be wrong but this is to give you the idea of what i was trying to do
(select case 
    when db2.boxoffice.movie_id = db1.movie.id then db1.tickets.movie_id= db2.boxoffice.movie_id
       else  db1.tickets.movie_id = db1.movie.id end)`

Expected Result -

`Tickets table`

`id movie_id`

Can someone help with the query, as I am not able to construct it?

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. What RDMS are you *really* using? Please retag the appropriate one

Comment: What have you tried so far to get the right answer? You've tagged `CASE`, which implies you know what it is. Why didn't the `CASE` expression you wrote not work? Please share it and explain the problem with it. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Are you sure that an if/case is needed? I fear that the result of the condition you wrote is always tickets.movie_id = movie.id

Comment: @Larnu I have updated what I wrote.

Comment: @Larnu I have updated the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can try this.

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
    SELECT b.movie_id
    FROM boxoffice b JOIN movie m
    ON b.movie_id = m.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m.id
    FROM boxoffice b JOIN movie m
    ON b.movie_id <> m.id
) t1 JOIN tickets t2 ON t1.movie_id = t2.movie_id
```

or you can try to use `LEFT JOIN` in subuqery

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
    SELECT (CASE WHEN m.id IS NOT NULL THEN b.movie_id ELSE m.id END) movie_id
    FROM boxoffice b LEFT JOIN movie m
    ON b.movie_id = m.id
) t1 JOIN tickets t2 ON t1.movie_id = t2.movie_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tickets.* (
  SELECT (
    CASE 
      WHEN movies.id IS NOT NULL THEN boxoffice.movie_id
      ELSE movies.id
    END
  ) AS movie_id
  FROM movies
  LEFT JOIN boxoffice ON boxoffice.movie_id = movies.id
) AS data_table
JOIN tickets ON tickets.movie_id = data_table.movie_id
```

Explanation:

`WHEN movies.id IS NOT NULL THEN boxoffice.movie_id`, check if there is a match like your if condition `if boxoffice.movie_id == movie.id`, if not it ignores those rows and considers only the movies.id